# Destroy GameObject when its clicked on

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm making a building mechanic in my game and I want to be able to clear out certain objects around the map (trees, other decor) so I have room to build. I've tried using a ray cast to find what object is being clicked on and destroy it but that doesn't work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectDestroy : MonoBehaviour {
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            Debug.Log (Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject) Destroy (gameObject);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have a 3D collider attached to the game object.

Comment: @Iggy everything has a collider

Comment: Have you already tested the onMouseDown()-method? If you have a collider on the object and the script attached to it, this should work also just by calling Destroy() in the onMouseDown()-method.

Comment: " if (hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject) Destroy (gameObject);" will check if the object that has this code is the same object as being clicked on is this really what you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little example script:

```
public class Destroyable : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

You can attach this script to the GameObject you want to destroy and then during Play-Mode you can click on it to destroy it. It is modifiable if you just need it in your In-Game-Editor.

Note: You need an active Collider on the same Gameobject.

Edit:

The following script shows an example for changing the color of the object:

```
public class Destroyable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color mouseHoverColor = Color.green;
    private Color previousColor;
    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        previousColor = meshRenderer.material.color;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        meshRenderer.material.color = mouseHoverColor;
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        meshRenderer.material.color = previousColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also note that objects should have a `collider` for this to work.

Comment: @AliKanat: Edited my answer. Just answered the specific question, suggested that the colliders are already there from the comment above and forgot to make it clear enough in general. So thank you for the tip!

Comment: @MSauer that works but is there a way to have the object selected in game (by hovering over it with your mouse) and when you press a certain key then it gets destroyed?

Comment: For your last comment, use my solution, create a script that is continuously raycasting and you highlight the one that is detected.

Comment: @Cri: Yes, you can use OnMouseOver() and OnMouseExit(). You also need a collider on this, which in your case is already attached and then you can handle you behaviour in it. An example with coloring is under this link(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add this script on every object, just add it to a manager and also I think you are missing Raycast parameters.

To see where you ray is going you can use `Debug.Ray()`

Also, I would prefer you use @MSauer way since is much cleaner for what you want, just be sure the object contains a collider, I think they can be a trigger and the click will still happen.